# Vault on EKS with KMS auto-unseal: "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, hashicorp-vault, amazon-kms, vault

I've installed **Vault 1.9.1** using the [Vault Helm Chart](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm) ver 0.18.0 in my AWS EKS cluster with kubernetes 1.21.0, I'm not able to init it typing the command:

```
kubectl --namespace=vault exec vault-0 -- vault operator init
```

I get the error

```
Error initializing: Put "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: 
connect: connection refused
```

The pod is running but not in READY status, the readiness probe fails due to:

```
Error checking seal status: Get "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
```

This is my chart values:

```
vault:
  injector:
    enabled: false
  csi:
    enabled: true
  server:
    enabled: true
    extraVolumes:
      - name: vault-storage-config
        type: secret
    extraArgs: -config=/vault/userconfig/vault-storage-config/config.hcl
    ha:
      enabled: true
      replicas: 3
```

and the `config.hcl`

```
ui = true

storage "postgresql" {
  connection_url = "postgres://<user>:<pwd>@<rds.url>/vault"
  table="vault_kv_store"
  ha_enabled="true"
  ha_table="vault_ha_locks"
}

service_registration "kubernetes" {}

seal "awskms" {
  kms_key_id = <my_kms_key_id>
}
```

I've enabled the auto-unseal feature leveraging the integration with AWS KMS.
I've already checked that the EKS worker nodes are able to reach the postgres RDS instance and able to call the AWS KMS service, they are granted to

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:DescribeKey",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in my own. I was focusing on the auto-unsealing feature supposing an issue on permissions, actually later I found out it was an issue related to the postgres data storage.
Due to the restarting, I lost the logs that later I was able to get typing

```
kubectl logs vault-0 -n mynamespace --previous
```

So I noticed the error

```
Error initializing storage of type postgresql: 
failed to check for native upsert: dial tcp <rds_ip_instance>:5342: connect: connection timed
```

Early I checked the reachability of the rds instance using psql from the host, but I didn't notice I misconfigured the postgres port `5343` instead `5432`.

Basically, I has been victim of the jumbled word effect that has driven me crazy for 2 long days!